# Android: onBufferingUpdate() not called after reaching 100%

Tags: android, video-streaming, buffer

I have a video running in a view.
The video is streamed from a server. The function

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int i)
```

is being called through out the time the video is streaming. For example, Even if the full video is buffered, while the video is playing, the buffer is getting drained out. So, the function is called. But this is valid only in lower versions of Android. In case of Android version above 4.0, the function is not called after the buffer value reaches 100, i.e., the period when the buffer is being emptied.

Does anyone know if this is a problem with Android or the ME type. What is the workaround one can carry out.?

Comment: What are you using it for? As far as I can see, it's now doing what it should. Only reporting while it's still buffering.

Comment: I create a graph for amount of buffer still filled. Now, it just stops after reaching the peak, while it should gradually reach Zero when the video is finished. This is working the way I want to in versions till 4.0.

Comment: The video has stopped buffering, so there is no sense in calling the method any more. But I reckon there ought to be playback callbacks that you could use to work around this.

Comment: Though the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html) still specifies the behavior that you mention. It might be a bug, but that I don't know.

Comment: Since the buffer is being emptied, the percentage is changed(updated). If that is not the case, what other workarounds can i use? I can think of a normal function that is called every second, and I update the graph there (or I manually call the onbufferingupdate from that function) .

Comment: @ManikandanKandasamy I've noticed this behavior on Moto G with Android 5.0. This method is still called after reaching 100% on few Samsung devices, which I've tested: Samsung Galaxy S3 (non updated - Android 4.0.4), Samsung Galaxy S3, Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0), Samsung Galaxy Note Pro (Android 4.4.2). I assume it has something common with Android modifications due to preparation it on different devices.

Comment: The one I was using was Sony Xperia Z3(I guess), but I am not sure I remember. In that case, I guess manual workaround is the only way?